# How to avoid truncating data when using Apache Beam FileIO

Tags: java, apache-beam

I want to preserve data from the previous stage while using Beam's built in `FileIO.matchAll()` transform.

I have a struct from the previous transform that looks like this:

```
public class MyStruct {
    public String filePattern;
    // Down below are some other metadata fields
    // I'd like to use in later transforms
    public String tableId
    ....
}
```

The problem is, in order to use `FileIO.matchAll()`, I need to truncate away other fields in the struct and only extract the `filePattern` field

```
myStructsPCollection
    .apply(
        MapElements
            .into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
            .via(MyStruct::getFilePattern))
    .apply(FileIO.matchAll());
    ...
```

Is there a way that I can still use `FileIO` without having to toss away other data in my struct? For example, something that will instruct `FileIO` to use the `MyStruct::getFilePattern` method to get the file pattern strings it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible. One solution could be to pass your `myStructsPCollection` as a [side input](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs) in a DoFn that follows the read and repopulate the other data matching based on the filename, like a join. (I assume `myStructsPCollection` would be much smaller than the data read.)